# understand the mysql subquery to write long tail query

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, subquery

I have checked several thread of stackoverflow.com about `subquery`. I also have check in MySQL documentation to understand the `subquery`. I would like to write long tail query in MySQL. I know there are huge experts who can help me to understand the following operators with an example for each operator and bind them within a long tail query.

`=,  >,  <,  >=,  <=,  <>,  !=, ANY, SOME, EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, IN, NOT IN, XOR, OR` etc. I have checked the operators meaning at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Mainly, I would like to learn the procedure to write a long tail query using above operators with an example.

I want to know the sequence of the syntax, [e.g- In a select query I have to write as follows-

```
1. select
2. all
3. from
4. tablename
5. where etc.
```

At the above sequence, I can't write `where` clause before table name. Isn't it? If you think this question is not written properly, then mention each point in comment, I'll improve immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For the Select Statement, the syntax is

```
    SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE condition
```

(*) means ALL , in place of it you can write column name if u want to retrieve a particular column

For the conditions i will give examples for some

```
    =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, ANY, SOME, EXISTS, NOT EXISTS, IN, NOT IN, XOR, OR 

    SELECT * FROM MyTable
    WHERE Name = 'Tijesunimi'
```

Retrives all details of the name (Tijesunimi)

```
    SELECT CustomerID, DateofBirth
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DateofBirth > '19530212' and CustomerID > '20'
```

Retrieves the CustomerID and Date of Birth where date of birth higher than 1953-Feb-12th and CustomerID is more than 20 (The same goes for >=,<=,<>)

```
    SELECT Id FROM MyTable
    WHERE 100 > ANY (SELECT Id, Amount FROM MyTable
                     WHERE Name = 'Tijesunimi')
```

Retrives id for customer where 100 greater than any value returned in the subquery

```
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM MyTable
                  WHERE Name = 'Tijesunimi)
```

Retrives all details for details of customer Tijesunimi

```
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM MyTable
                  WHERE Name = 'Tijesunimi)
```

Retrives details for other customers apart from 'Tijesunimi'

I have explained the ones i know well...
I hope it helps you